# Inclined plane problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, friction

[image]

This is the problem question from my textbook. My questions are concerning some formulas related to this problem. The force of friction is obviously down the plane.

My initial question is: $F_{friction}={\mu}{F_{N}}$. However, the man is applying a force in the same direction as $F_{N}$. Does this affect the initial formula? Does this become $F_{friction}={\mu}{F_{off}}$ where $F_{off}=F_{friction}+F_{A}{\sin20^{\circ}}$ ($F_A$ is the force applied by the man)?

My next question is related to my initial question. $F_p=F_w\sin35^\circ$ and $F_N=F_w\cos35^\circ$. In this case case would $F_w\sin35^\circ=F_p+F_{friction}$ or just $F_w\sin35^\circ=F_p$ ($F_p$ is the force the block exerts down the plane)? Similarly, would $F_w\cos35^\circ=F_N+F_{A}{\sin20^{\circ}}$ or just $F_w\cos35^\circ=F_N$?

Finally, what is the actual solution to the problem? The book says $464\:\mathrm{N}$ but an online worked solution says $953\:\mathrm{N}$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this affect the initial formula? Does this become Ffriction=μFoff where Foff=**Ffriction**+FAsin20∘ (FA is the force applied by the man)?

for above case you are talking about normal force hence no friction instead Wsin35.

and your second question is basically the answer for your above as  **Fwcos35∘=FN+FAsin20∘**  this is correct.

i would stick with 953N and even that is not exact as it depends what the solution manual guy took g=?

i took g as 9.81 and got 934 N however with g=10 i got 952 N[image]

Comment: This is a mathjax-enabled site; so please utilise this facility; otherwise it is quite a tough work to conceive the writings.

Comment: Well I am new to the site, thanks for letting me know and besides you needed another solution to verify and i gave you a detailed one, so i hope your query was solved at least by the typed answer